# SimpleForm default input class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm using SimpleForm + Bootstrap. How can I add an attribute to all `type="text"` inputs with class = `span12`?

Something that outputs something like this:

```
<div class="controls"><input autofocus="autofocus" class="string required span12" id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" required="required" size="50" type="text" value=""></div>
```

I tried playing with `config.wrappers` but this

```
ba.use :input,  :wrap_with => { :class => 'span12' }
```

doesn't work. It adds to wrapper instead of modifying the input tag. Any thoughts?

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.wrappers :bootstrap, :tag => 'div', :class => 'control-group', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-inline' }
      ba.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'p', :class => 'help-block' }
    end
  end
  config.default_wrapper = :bootstrap
end
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply override the simple_form default for string input by adding a string_input.rb class file to your rails load path (i.e. app/inputs/string_input.rb) and include as follow:

```
class StringInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  def input_html_classes
    super.push('span12')
  end
end
```

If you need to add more default classes to other types of input, you can check out the various input types provided:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/tree/master/lib/simple_form/inputs

Comment: I guess this can be used as a temporary solution until the configuration will allow it.

Comment: For those who arrived here via Google, this is now supported as of v2.2 (see [changelog](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/v2.2/CHANGELOG.md)) with an `config.input_class` call, but that also wraps the container div in the same class, which makes bootstrap styling wonky. Thus, this answer is still probably the best solution, even though the config allows setting classes on all inputs.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and after some research I found out that this is not supported using the wrapper api.

> The best you can do is use the :defaults option in each form, instead of adding for every input.

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/754

You can achieve this like this: `simple_form_for(@my_instance, defaults: { input_html: { class: 'span12' }})`

You can also choose to use a custom formbuilder.
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#custom-form-builder