# bootstrap3 + simple_form + client side validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form, client-side-validation

Not sure this is the right place to share my way to mix three together, but I don't have blog or git account, and the problem cost me 2 days to solve, so maybe there is some one hanging there. I would like to share my solution.

**1. simple_form**

simple_form is not supporting bootstrap 3 yet, but someone has solve the problem. You can find it at following links:

[SimpleForm default input class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972253/simpleform-default-input-class)

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/316

```
#simple_form_bootstrap.rb in the initializers
inputs = %w[
  CollectionSelectInput
  DateTimeInput
  FileInput
  GroupedCollectionSelectInput
  NumericInput
  PasswordInput
  RangeInput
  StringInput
  TextInput
]

inputs.each do |input_type|
  superclass = "SimpleForm::Inputs::#{input_type}".constantize

  new_class = Class.new(superclass) do
    def input_html_classes
      super.push('form-control')
    end
  end

  Object.const_set(input_type, new_class)
end

# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.boolean_style = :nested

  config.wrappers :bootstrap3, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error',
              defaults: { input_html: { class: 'default_class' } } do |b|

    b.use :html5
    b.use :min_max
    b.use :maxlength
    b.use :placeholder

    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :readonly

    b.use :label_input
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block has-error' }
  end

  config.wrappers :bootstrap3_horizontal, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error',
              defaults: { input_html: { class: 'default-class '}, wrapper_html: { class: "col-lg-10 col-md-10"} } do |b|

    b.use :html5
    b.use :min_max
    b.use :maxlength
    b.use :placeholder

    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :readonly

    b.use :label
    b.wrapper :right_column, tag: :div do |component|
      component.use :input
    end
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block has-error' }
  end

  config.wrappers :group, tag: 'div', class: "form-group", error_class: 'has-error',
              defaults: { input_html: { class: 'default-class '} }  do |b|

    b.use :html5
    b.use :min_max
    b.use :maxlength
    b.use :placeholder

    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :readonly

    b.use :label
    b.use :input, wrap_with: { class: "input-group" }
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block has-error' }
  end

  config.default_wrapper = :bootstrap3
end
```

**2. View**

keep in mind, the bootstrap3 structure of the html code is different from bootstrap2.
basically, the form sentence is:

```
=simple_form_for(resource,
                 wrapper: :bootstrap3_horizontal, //I'm using bootstrap3_horizontal layout. you can find it in the initializer. 
                 defaults: {right_column_html: {class: "col-lg-4 col-md-4"}, 
                            label_html: {class: "col-lg-3 col-md-3"} }
```

**3. client side validation**

I installed 2 gems for validation
- client_side_validations
- client_side_validations-simple_form

Please be noted, these two gems are no longer maintained. However, my application goes too far to change to another method.

If you still want go ahead, copy the asset to application:

```
rails g client_side_validations:copy_assets
```

open rails.validations.simple_form.js, change it to flowing:

```
(function() {

    ClientSideValidations.formBuilders['SimpleForm::FormBuilder'] = {
        add: function(element, settings, message) {
            return this.wrappers[settings.wrapper].add.call(this, element, settings, message);
        },
        remove: function(element, settings) {
            return this.wrappers[settings.wrapper].remove.call(this, element, settings);
        },
        wrappers: {
            //default wrapper is not changed.
            "default": { 
                add: function(element, settings, message) {
                    var errorElement, wrapper;
                    errorElement = element.parent().find("" + settings.error_tag + "." + settings.error_class);
                    wrapper = element.closest(settings.wrapper_tag);
                    if (!(errorElement[0] != null)) {
                        errorElement = $("<" + settings.error_tag + "/>", {
                            "class": settings.error_class,
                            text: message
                        });
                        wrapper.append(errorElement);
                    }
                    wrapper.addClass(settings.wrapper_error_class);
                    return errorElement.text(message);
                },
                remove: function(element, settings) {
                    var errorElement, wrapper;
                    wrapper = element.closest("" + settings.wrapper_tag + "." + settings.wrapper_error_class);
                    wrapper.removeClass(settings.wrapper_error_class);
                    errorElement = wrapper.find("" + settings.error_tag + "." + settings.error_class);
                    return errorElement.remove();
                }
            },
            // I'm using horizontal form layout, so the wrapper is bootstrap3_horizontal, which is in the initializer and view form.
            bootstrap3_horizontal: {  // changed
                add: function(element, settings, message) {
                    var errorElement, errorSpan, wrapper_class_element, wrapper_tag_element;
                    errorSpan = settings.error_tag+"[class=\'"+settings.error_class+"\']";  //changed
                    errorElement = element.parent().find(errorSpan);  //changed
                    if (!(errorElement[0] != null)) {
                        wrapper_tag_element = element.closest(settings.wrapper_tag);
                        errorElement = $("<"     + settings.error_tag + "/>", {
                            "class": settings.error_class,
                            text: message
                        });
                        wrapper_tag_element.append(errorElement);
                    }
                    wrapper_class_element = element.closest("." + settings.wrapper_class);
                    wrapper_class_element.addClass(settings.wrapper_error_class);
                    return errorElement.text(message);
                },
                remove: function(element, settings) {
                    var errorElement, errorSpan, wrapper_class_element, wrapper_tag_element;
                    wrapper_class_element = element.closest("." + settings.wrapper_class + "." + settings.wrapper_error_class);
                    wrapper_tag_element = element.closest(settings.wrapper_tag);
                    wrapper_class_element.removeClass(settings.wrapper_error_class);
                    errorSpan = settings.error_tag+"[class=\'"+settings.error_class+"\']";   //changed
                    errorElement = wrapper_tag_element.find(errorSpan);  //changed
                    return errorElement.remove();
                }
            }

        }
    };

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what Rails version you are using?

Comment: @R_G rails3 on 1.9.3

Comment: That must be Ruby.  Run the command "rails -v" to see the rails version.  Heck, I don't even see a question here, let alone a solution.  What did you want?